# Cannot Get a Azure Webjobs Job To Send An Email Stored in Blob Storage As an Htm File

Tags: azure-webjobs

Having problems diagnosing why a webjob won't work. I'm trialing Azure.

There's no errors. But I am never receiving the email which the WebJob is meant to be sending.

I tried clicking the big Functions rectangle in the top right of the header (it had an exclamation point icon in it). But that was just an empty page with the footer flush up against the header.

The code is simply:

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage(
    [BlobInput("notifications/{name}")] Stream input,
    [BlobOutput("notifications/{name}")] Stream output)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(input))
    {       
        using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
        {
            smtp.Host = "smtp.adam.com.au";
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

            smtp.Timeout = 5000;
            var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("anemail@gmail.com"));

            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("dave@dave.com");

            mailMessage.Subject = "nice email";
            mailMessage.Body = sr.ReadToEnd();
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            smtp.Send(mailMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

This is black box to me. How can I diagnose the problem?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? send an email every time a blob is uploaded to storage? or are you trying to do something whenever a message is added to the queue?

Comment: @lopezbertoni Yes. When uploaded. Updating to latest beta fixed the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are using the old version of the SDK. The new one, Beta, has different attribute names. Without upgrading, you will not be able to see any data in the dashboard.

Second, you see the exclamation point because the connection string is not properly configured in the Configure tab of the website. Set a connection string named AzureJobsDashboard.

Last, here is how you can debug the webjob in the cloud http://blog.mitchdenny.com/2014/02/11/remotely-debugging-web-jobs-on-windows-azure-websites/

Comment: Thanks. I've updated to the latest and it all works straight away.